# "Provider org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JProvider not found" error, in Spring boot 2.0.2 app

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

My Spring boot app is facing this error when trying to run the jar, but not while running in the Intellij:

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.Provider: Provider org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JProvider not found
```

Yet, when running `mvn dependency:tree` I can see the slf4j jars:

```
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
```

And

```
 +- org.testcontainers:testcontainers:jar:1.7.1:test
 |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
 |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-ext:jar:1.7.25:test
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the class is picked up by one of your test dependencies, so it's in the classpath when you run in IntelliJ, but when you build a runnable jar it doesn't get pulled into the fat jar.

Have a look at what jar it's in and check that isn't in the test scope.